# Racket Sum of Perfect Roots Implementation

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I am trying to write a Racket function that takes in a list of numbers as the input, and outputs the sum of the square roots of those numbers in the list that are perfect squares. The code I have currently does not compile, and is as follows:

```
(define (sum-of-perfect-roots lst)
  (apply + (map (lambda (number)
                  (sqrt number)) (filter (exact? sqrt(number)) lst))))
```

I know that my error lies in the usage of the predicate for the filter function. I don't know how to return the list of only perfect squares correctly. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Racket actually has a built-in math library, and the `math/number-theory` module provides a convenient [`perfect-square` function](http://docs.racket-lang.org/math/number-theory.html?q=number%20theory#%28def._%28%28lib._math%2Fnumber-theory..rkt%29._perfect-square%29%29). The documentation for `perfect-square` describes it as follows:

> Returns `(sqrt m)` if `m` is perfect square, otherwise `#f`.

This, of course, makes implementing your function trivial. You could just do something like this:

```
(require math/number-theory)

(define (sum-of-perfect-roots lst)
  (apply + (filter-map perfect-square lst)))
```

Using `filter-map` is also more efficient, since it doesn't need to build the list twice. Still, if you'd rather roll your own implementation for learning purposes, reimplementing `perfect-square` would not be terribly difficult.

```
(define (perfect-square n)
  (define root (sqrt n))
  (if (integer? root) root #f))
```

If you wanted to make it more efficient, you could avoid building the intermediate list entirely by using `fold`. Racket's `for/sum` comprehension form makes this easy to implement.

```
(define (sum-of-perfect-roots lst)
  (for/sum ([n (in-list lst)])
    (or (perfect-square n) 0)))
```

Comment: You can also use `integer-sqrt/remainder`: `(define (perfect-square n) (define-values (q r) (integer-sqrt/remainder n)) (and (zero? r) q))`. Also, for your `for` version of `sum-of-perfect-roots`, in this case, it's easier to just use `for/sum` instead of `for/fold`.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Thanks for the `for/sum` point—I always forget that exists for some reason.

Comment: Anyway, my edited comment includes a `integer-sqrt/remainder` version of `perfect-square`. :-D (I try to avoid floating-point if it can be avoided, but that's just me.)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young `sqrt` is exact if its input is exact and its output is rational, but `integer-sqrt` might be faster.

Comment: Also, you can use `(for*/sum ((n (in-list lst)) (r (in-value (perfect-square n))) #:when r) r)`. `in-value` provides something akin to `let` in comprehensions. :-)